# adjust image to fixed content

Tags: html, css, image

I'm dealing with img tags which are have a fixed width & height.

The question is that a have a set of images that each one has its own dimensions, so in the resulting view, some of them vary in height keeping the width constant.

This is what I get:
[image]

... and this is what I want to accomplish:
[image]

Is there any way that whatever image is loaded in the img tag keep proportions and be all with the same height?

Comment: i think, you need image resizer script in any server side programming language

Comment: Take a look at Backstretch jQuery plugin. If you want to retain the aspect, it will help you. Refer demo: On a block level element there. http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

you can use css and set the property of width and height to what ever you want

```css
img 
{
  width : 150px;
  height : 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/57825/pexels-photo-57825.jpeg" alt="no image available" />
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/149941/pexels-photo-149941.jpeg" alt="no image available" />
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/163145/laptop-computer-coffee-yellow-163145.jpeg" alt="no image available" />
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7107/notebook-hero-workspace-minimal.jpg" alt="no image available" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:
1. Put the images into 'div's
 Eg.

```
<div class='image-container'>
       <img src="yourimage.jpg">
     </div>
```

2. adjust the height of the in the stylesheet:

   ```
   .image-container img{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
   ```

   }
3. adjust the width of the 'div's to fill quarter of the page:
     .image-container{
        width: 25%;
   }

Comment: I've tried your solution with no success. The output is the same.

Comment: You forgot to set a height to class='image-container' due to without setting it, by default is auto.

Comment: Indeed. For the height to work in percentages, the parent's height need to be first defined. You may need to set the parent of the class "image-container". Please try doing so.

Comment: Found the better solution:  I set class='image-container' with a height based on the following calc: height:calc(25vw * 300.0 / 500);

Comment: Okay, that seems nice.